# php mail function having issues with multiple recipients?

Tags: php

PHP mail function works fine if all the addresses are valid and sends mail to each one of them but in case any of the email id is not valid (i mean does not exist) The mail function does not works. Has anyone faced similar problem is there a fix for the same or should i try validating all the email id's existence myself.

Answer (score 0):

just loop all the addresses - should work independent then.
(Except you NEED to show everybody all recipients)

```
    foreach ($emails as $email){
      //do mail stuff.
    }
```

You can also add some error handling to collect the invalid addresses then.